# twig loop to output only one td

Tags: html, twig

I have the following twig loop which generates some data:

```
    {% for reservationDate, rooms in data.pricingTable %}
        <tr>

            <td>
                {% for room in rooms  %}

                    <tr>
                        <td class="date"><p>{{ reservationDate }}</p></td>
                        <td class="roomType">
                            <p>
                                {{ room.description }} ({{ room.bathroomDescription }} {{ 'ROOMDETAILSBATHROOM'|trans }})
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="people">
                            <p>
                                {{ room.noPeople }}
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="pricePerPerson">
                            <p>
                                {{ room.pricePerPerson }}<span>{{ room.currency }}</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="total">
                            <p>
                                {{ room.total }}<span>{{ room.currency }}</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

by doing so the:

```
<td class="date"><p>{{ reservationDate }}</p></td>
```

gets repeated many times based on how many:

```
{{ room.description }} ({{ room.bathroomDescription }} {{ 'ROOMDETAILSBATHROOM'|trans }})
```

will be generated.

I have tried to use "rowspan" but the implies using a dynamic value to insert in, so a JS solution which I don't really want to.

Is there a way to have only one:

```
<td class="date"><p>{{ reservationDate }}</p></td>
```

regardless of how many:

```
{{ room.description }} ({{ room.bathroomDescription }} {{ 'ROOMDETAILSBATHROOM'|trans }})
```

This seems to work, but it produces an empty row for every set of results:

```
                {% for room in rooms  %}

                    <tr>
                        <td class="date">
                        {% if loop.first %} 
                            <p>{{ reservationDate }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        </td>
                        <td class="roomType">
                            <p>
                                {{ room.description }} ({{ room.bathroomDescription }} {{ 'ROOMDETAILSBATHROOM'|trans }})
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="people">
                            <p>
                                {{ room.noPeople }}
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="pricePerPerson">
                            <p>
                                {{ room.pricePerPerson }}<span>{{ room.currency }}</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="total">
                            <p>
                                {{ room.total }}<span>{{ room.currency }}</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

are genrated from the loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the loop variables that you will find [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) creating something like this:

```
{% for room in rooms  %}

    ...

    {% if loop.first %} 
        <td class="date"><p>{{ reservationDate }}</p></td>
    {% endif %}

    ...

{% endfor %}
```

With `loop.length` you even have a variable for use as `rowspan`.

Comment: I will check this solution out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery with this code:

```
 $('.date').not(':last').remove();
```

This will automaticly remove all the duplicates

Like this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eyrexwb6/

Comment: Hi yes, that works but I would prefer a HTML solution if possible.

Comment: not sure how twig works you can maybe take a look here http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters and filter the duplicates out or put a if inside the forloop wich only works the first time it comes trough?

Comment: Question is related to twig, not jQuery.